# Swaping Characters [Not Material but Skeletal Mesh] In a level Unreal c++

Tags: unreal-engine4

So I was working on a proto where I want to implement a character swap functionality in the game.

I'm not talking about swapping the camera component from one character to another or changing the material used in a mesh, but rather changing the whole skeletal mesh so that the player can use the new character to complete the mission/Level.

(Note: The swapped character will have different animations, attacks and everything).

I Saw some Bp tutorial in youtube but they use "Set Skeletal Mesh" which can easily change the skeletal mesh using some conditions... but I want to implement this in c++.

Can anyone Help me to understand the logic...The Logic I have in mind is to use an array to store the Uskeletal component and choose the meshes available but I don't know if this is possible or optimised.. !! Valid Suggestions will be Greatly appreciated (Sry for the spelling and Grammer)

Answer (score 0):

You can keep an array of skeletal meshes as `UPROPERTY` on your character class. Just keeping them around does not automatically visualize or use them in any way.

To do that you need to create and attach a `USkeletalMeshComponent` to the character. If you look at component's interface, you will see a `SetSkeletalMesh(class USkeletalMesh* NewMesh)` method you can use to actually set the mesh used and rendered by the component.